# postgreSQL date records only persisting up to a certain point in time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, date

I am seeding some simple data in my rails program that is using a postgres database.

Currently, it is only persisting certain dates to the database.  Other times, it is showing up as `null` in my API, which is very odd.  I will post a picture of my database, and the seeded data, as well as my `JSON` API.

Here is my table:

```
create_table "pickup_deliveries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "pickup_date"
    t.text "pickup_location"
    t.money "rate", scale: 2
    t.date "delivery_date"
    t.text "delivery_location"
    t.boolean "local"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "loaded_miles", default: 0
    t.integer "deadhead_miles", default: 0
  end
```

Here is my seeded data:

```
PickupDelivery.create(:pickup_date => '05-10-2019', :pickup_location => 'Kansas City, MO', :rate => '550.00', :delivery_date => '05-11-2019', :delivery_location => 'Wichita, KS', :local => false, :loaded_miles => '550', :deadhead_miles =>'230');
PickupDelivery.create(:pickup_date => '05-20-2019', :pickup_location => 'Kansas City, MO', :rate => '550.00', :delivery_date => '05-25-2019', :delivery_location => 'Wichita, KS', :local => false, :loaded_miles => '550', :deadhead_miles =>'230');
```

Here is the persisted data in my `JSON` API:

```
[
{
id: 1,
pickup_date: "2019-10-05",
pickup_location: "Kansas City, MO",
rate: "550.0",
delivery_date: "2019-11-05",
delivery_location: "Wichita, KS",
local: false,
created_at: "2019-05-09T16:14:35.312Z",
updated_at: "2019-05-09T16:14:35.312Z",
loaded_miles: 550,
deadhead_miles: 230
},
{
id: 2,
pickup_date: null,
pickup_location: "Kansas City, MO",
rate: "550.0",
delivery_date: null,
delivery_location: "Wichita, KS",
local: false,
created_at: "2019-05-09T16:14:35.319Z",
updated_at: "2019-05-09T16:14:35.319Z",
loaded_miles: 550,
deadhead_miles: 230
}
]
```

As you can see, the dates were both inputted in the same format, but only one came out as intended while the other came out as `null`

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are passing an invalid format in the second record

```rb
# Record 1
:delivery_date => '05-11-2019' # dd-mm-yyyy
# to
delivery_date: "2019-11-05"

# Record 2
:delivery_date => '05-25-2019' # dd-mm-yyyy
# Invalud since there is no month 25
so it becomes nil
```

This date is being parsed as `dd-mm-yyyy`

The date you are passing in the second record is invalid due to the month

I suggest you pass the date in this format 'dd-mm-yyyy' - '20-05-2019'

**NOTE:** Even in your first record the date in being parsed as 05 the day, 11 as the month and 2019 as the year

Comment: By "I suggest you pass the date in this format 'dd-mm-yyyy' - '20-05-2019'" don't you man "I suggest you pass the date in this format 'yyyy-mm-dd' - '2019-05-20'", using ISO 8601 standard formats is generally a good idea.